# Smooth edges after using spin tool

Tags: edges

I am making a coffee cup from Blender Guru. He used in his video the spin tool to make the handle of the cup. But after he used the spin tool he had a very smooth handle. But mine handle has very weird edges. How could I fix or smooth these edges? Here are some photos.

[image: Edges1]

[image: Edge edit mode]

[image: Edge edit mode]

What do I need to do to smooth those edges?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You dont need so many loops, delete one problematic on upper part or few of them to make distribution more even ... or try to search smooth operator with those vertices selected and adjust Factor or Repeatness.

Comment: @moonboots I have uploaded the blend file

Comment: please share the URL ti has created, as vklidu says you need to dissolve some edge loops, at least on the top of the handle (Ctrl X), maybe it's the same on the bottom but it's better to check

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/media/1/b/1b8b1ac969b5ede1bcdf5d795ae87173.blend

Comment: @moonboots I have tried to press X and use the options `Dissolve Vertices` `Dissolve Edges` `Dissolve Faces` and `Edge Loops` But every option is making it worse. Only Dissolve Faces is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices at the bottom and probably somewhere else, so select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

This edge loop is too close to the one on the left, it creates this bad bump, switch to *Edge select* mode, select it and dissolve it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Everything is smooth now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown this is caused by distortions in the geometry near where the "wierd" stuff's happening.

The bottom of the handle looks like it may have duplicated geometry.  I'd recommend you start by selecting everything in the object and Merge by Distance (M key, the Distance options last one down in the pop-up).

The top of the handle shows some vertices out of position for a smooth surface.  There are a few different ways to fix (or at least improve) this kind of issue, this one requires the Mesh: Relax add-on (included with Blender) to be enabled.  Select the distorted vertices or faces, Ctrl-V > Relax (it's the last option in the Vertex menu) then expand the Parameters box (near lower left corner of the window) and up the number of iterations (not too many, what you're showing shouldn't take more than five, and three would probably work, even one might be enough).

However, following the instructions of that tutorial (if I'm looking at the right one) this should'nt've happened, you might want to go back and try it again, see if you can find what went wrong in the first place.  Both skill sets (doing it "right" the first time, fixing issues) are needed in 3D art.

Comment: I can't find the Relax option. Or did you mean something else?  My last option in the Vertex menu is Make Vertex Parent.

Comment: Sorry, that requires the Mesh: Relax add-on (included with Blender) to be enabled, I forgot.  I've edited my answer.